# Why can't I pass an rvalue-reference as it is to another function in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I have a code:

```
void f(int&& i) {
  auto lambda = [](int&& j) { (void)j; }
  lambda(i);
}

int main() {
  f(5);
}
```

Clang++ gives an error: `no known conversion from 'int' to 'int &&' for 1st argument`

Why the `i` changes its type to `int` when being passed to the `lambda()`?

Comment: It helps to distinguish between the variable named `i` which has type `int&&`, and the expression written `i` that is the result of evaluating that variable which has type `int` and value category `lvalue`. It's easy to conflate the two when we represent both with the same syntax. The same sort of thing happens with `int i` (variable of type `int`, lvalue expression of type `int`) and `int& i` (variable of type `int&`, lvalue expression of type `int`), but the difference between the type of the variable and the type of the expression that evaluates it becomes more important with rvalue refs.

Comment: @Casey: Yours is the best answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @TonyK It doesn't stand on its own without the other answers (all three of which I upvoted), I just thought it would help to better understand them. Us experienced folk are used to it, but its very confusing to newer programmers that `i` means different things in different contexts. Rvalue references are *hard* to teach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two elements at work here:

- **Type**: The parameter `i` has type `int&&`, or "rvalue reference to `int`", where "rvalue reference" is the name for the `&&` feature, allowing binding *rvalues* to a reference;
- **Value category**: This is the key. `i` has a name and so the expression naming it is an *lvalue*, regardless of its type or what the standard committee decided to call that type. :)

<sub>(Note that the *expression* that looks like `i` has type `int`, not `int&&`, because reasons. The rvalue ref is lost when you start to use the parameter, unless you use something like `std::move` to get it back.)</sub>

Comment: May I assume that the `i` actually gets type `int` (or `int&`?) after the function matching (with temporary rvalue object) is applied? Is it true in all situations where the `int&&` is used, that it's really just the `int` (or `int&`)?

Comment: @M.M: As an expression, yes. I'll clarify. Ta

Answer (score 15):

`i` is of type `int&&`, that is, it's of type "rvalue reference to `int`." However, note that `i` itself *is an lvalue* (because it has a name). And as an lvalue, it cannot bind to a "reference to rvalue."

To bind it, you must turn it back to an rvalue, using `std::move()` or `std::forward()`.

To expand a bit: the type of an expression and its value category are (largely) independent concepts. The *type* of `i` is `int&&`. The *value category* of `i` is lvalue.

Comment: I totally miss the point - how the `lvalue` can have type `rvalue reference`, but be not able to bind to the same type `rvalue reference`? Are there any similar examples in C++ with other types? - Or should I just remember, that only rvalue references behave like that?

Comment: @abyss.7: It having a "rvalue-reference" type doesn't make it an _rvalue_ in terms of value category. The name "rvalue-reference" was a bit of a silly choice, really.

Comment: RValueness isn't a characteristic of a variable, it's a characteristic of an expression. (well, except in some specific template-y cases). In the expression `lambda(i)`, both "lambda" and "i" are lvalues because they have names. In the expression from my answer, `lambda(std::move(i))` lambda is still an lvalue, i is still an lvalue, but std::move(i) is an rvalue.

Comment: @Abyss Yes, there are. Look at `const char * p;` for example. `p` is a pointer to a constant character, but p itself is *not* constant. I find it helpful to mentally rewrite "rvalue reference" as "reference to rvalue". The expression that the reference was initialized with is an rvalue, not the reference itself.

Comment: The type of *the expression* `i` is `int`.   (Expressions don't have reference type).

Answer (score 4):

`i` is a name, and any object accessed by name is automatically an LValue, even though your parameter is marked as an rvalue reference. You can cast `i` back to an rvalue by using `std::move` or `std::forward`

```
void f(int&& i) {
  auto lambda = [](int&& j) { (void)j; };
  lambda(std::move(i));
}

int main() {
  f(5);
}
```